# Admin panel jquery issue in magento

Tags: jquery, magento, admin

In magento admin panel when add new product showing console error.

Error is :

```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined
   Uncaught ReferenceError: Fieldset is not defined
   Uncaught ReferenceError: Translate is not defined
   Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined 
   Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined
   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
   Uncaught ReferenceError: varienTabs is not defined
   Uncaught ReferenceError: varienForm is not defined
   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
   Uncaught TypeError: Event.observe is not a function
```

And also check error list in attached file.
[magento admin panel jquery console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRxnl.png)

Please help how can fix this error.

Thankyou.

Comment: can you  give us your password the username and the url we have :)))

Comment: check you logs,it seems that jquery and/or other js libraries aren't properly loading or are not referenced properly

Comment: Can we do with teamviewer?

Comment: I have got solution remove defer from all scripit tag